# Whenever I try to upgrade,update and install any software on Ubuntu18.04 I get unmet dependencies error

Tags: 18.04, python3

It was all working fine but after i did `sudo apt upgrade` i got a red dash icon on my notification bar and started facing conflicts with python versions,

when trying :

> `sudo apt upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.7 : Depends: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.10-1+bionic2) but 3.7.9-1+xenial1 is installed
 libpython3.7-dev : Depends: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.10-1+bionic2) but 3.7.9-1+xenial1 is installed
 libpython3.7-stdlib : Depends: libpython3.7-minimal (= 3.7.9-1+xenial1) but 3.7.10-1+bionic2 is installed
 python3.7 : Depends: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.10-1+bionic2) but 3.7.9-1+xenial1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

when i did :

> `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python3.7-distutils python3.7-lib2to3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython3.7-stdlib
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3.7-stdlib
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 78 not upgraded.
57 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,791 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.2 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 211389 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.10-1+bionic2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.7-stdlib:amd64 (3.7.10-1+bionic2) over (3.7.9-1+xenial1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.10-1+bionic2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/__init__.py', which is also in package python3.7-distutils 3.7.9-1+xenial1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.10-1+bionic2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

as requested in comment for

> grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20190227)]/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ bionic universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src https://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ bionic universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list.distUpgrade:deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-ffmpeg-4-xenial.list.save:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-4/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-ffmpeg-4-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-4/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/neovim-ppa-ubuntu-unstable-bionic.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/unstable/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/neovim-ppa-ubuntu-unstable-bionic.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/unstable/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:# deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/ # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teejee2008-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teejee2008-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnome-terminator-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnome-terminator-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list.save:# deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/ # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list.distUpgrade:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-vim-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-vim-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-ffmpeg-4-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-4/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-ffmpeg-4-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-4/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-vim-bionic.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list.save:# deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian_10/ ./ # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-obs.list:# deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-vim-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-vim-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/go-for-it-team-ubuntu-go-for-it-stable-xenial.list.save:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/go-for-it-team/go-for-it-stable/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/go-for-it-team-ubuntu-go-for-it-stable-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/go-for-it-team/go-for-it-stable/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linrunner-ubuntu-tlp-xenial.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linrunner-ubuntu-tlp-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/appgrid-stable.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/appgrid/stable/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list:# deb [arch=amd64,arm64] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnome-terminator-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnome-terminator-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/neovim-ppa-ubuntu-stable-bionic.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/stable/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/neovim-ppa-ubuntu-stable-bionic.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/stable/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list.save:# deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list.save:# deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-xenial.list.save:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/appgrid-stable.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/appgrid/stable/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/neovim-ppa-ubuntu-stable-bionic.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/stable/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/neovim-ppa-ubuntu-stable-bionic.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/stable/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list.distUpgrade:deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list.distUpgrade:deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-xenial.list.save:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-xenial.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list.distUpgrade:deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian_10/ ./
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64,arm64] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/go-for-it-team-ubuntu-go-for-it-stable-xenial.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/go-for-it-team/go-for-it-stable/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/go-for-it-team-ubuntu-go-for-it-stable-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/go-for-it-team/go-for-it-stable/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list:# deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list:# deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.save:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-obs.list.distUpgrade:deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_16.04 ./
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/appgrid-stable.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/appgrid/stable/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-vim-xenial.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-vim-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linrunner-ubuntu-tlp-xenial.list.save:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linrunner-ubuntu-tlp-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linrunner-ubuntu-tlp-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linrunner-ubuntu-tlp-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list:# deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian_10/ ./ # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-obs.list.save:# deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/neovim-ppa-ubuntu-unstable-bionic.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/unstable/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/neovim-ppa-ubuntu-unstable-bionic.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/unstable/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/obs.list.save:deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/ ./
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-ffmpeg-4-xenial.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-4/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-ffmpeg-4-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-4/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/numix-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/numix-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teejee2008-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teejee2008-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/numix-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/numix-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-xenial.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-vim-bionic.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/obs.list:deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/ ./
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teejee2008-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teejee2008-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list.save:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list.save:# deb [arch=amd64,arm64] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/go-for-it-team-ubuntu-go-for-it-stable-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/go-for-it-team/go-for-it-stable/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/go-for-it-team-ubuntu-go-for-it-stable-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/go-for-it-team/go-for-it-stable/ubuntu xenial main
```

> sudo apt policy libpython3.7-stdlib

```
libpython3.7-stdlib:
  Installed: 3.7.9-1+xenial1
  Candidate: 3.7.10-1+bionic2
  Version table:
     3.7.10-1+bionic2 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.7.9-1+xenial1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.7.5-2~18.04.4 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages
     3.7.0~b3-1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

my source.list file:

> cat /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20190227)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
# deb-src http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/
# deb-src https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main
deb https://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src https://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ bionic universe
```

Comment: xenial package? `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` please add this to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Please add output of `sudo apt policy libpython3.7-stdlib`

Comment: added that output, i tried those steps from thread you shared @pLumo but it didn't work for me

Comment: Ok, now it is clear what happened. See here same issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066823/how-can-i-remove-python-3-6-installed-from-deadsnakes-ppa-after-upgrade-to-ubunt. You will need to change all `3.6` to `3.7` in the solution.

Comment: Mr pLumo, I guess after removing python3.6 i messed it up all :-| , is there anyway to reinstall distro without loosing the data?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of `ppa`'s installed in your system. You should check if you still need them and  consider removing at least some of them:

I see some faulty ones:

1. How did this `artful-updates` line come to your system? Remove it!

   ```
   sed -i '/artful-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. The `gnome-terminator` repo does not provide `bionic` sources, you have to remove it:

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnome-terminator-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
   ```

   You can simply use the one from `universe` repo which is already enabled.

---

In the end, run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt -f install` and see if that helps.

Please refer also to this question: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

---

Not a problem, but you still might want to remove the `.save` and `.distUpgrade` files to clean up your `sources.list.d` directory:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.save /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.distUpgrade
```

Comment: gnome-terminator is the shell i use, first one i dont know about it

Comment: The shell is probably `bash` or so, you mean `terminal`. It's fine to use `terminator`, but this repository cannot be used for it. It is however in `universe` repository which you have already enabled