# hash sum mismatch, you have held broken packages, unable to fetch etc

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, dependencies

I am using ubuntu 18.04

When I make `sudo apt-get update`, this is the output:

```
Hit:1 http://ubuntu.vargonen.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://ubuntu.vargonen.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]               
Hit:3 http://ubuntu.vargonen.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                     
Get:4 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease [1.487 B]                
Get:5 http://ubuntu.vargonen.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [413 kB]
Err:5 http://ubuntu.vargonen.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:412704 [weak]
   - SHA256:93358166c270b6b92fa9b2f22a2b48682eab53091a898321d887541133721297
   - SHA1:18d14381256ffb6581e1a46b11d911a3cfe6c7ad [weak]
   - MD5Sum:925906a34ad2a7f04f96fa373fb4d672 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:8963f74a7233a0b6d3fef6305755210d987563d34f3d4f9baad34985c3f2f2f8
   - SHA1:4fe0dbdb757e94d9217ae262253ffa29737b92fa [weak]
   - MD5Sum:12d989921f2d8efe120ea70cb64ac867 [weak]
   - Filesize:412704 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Tue, 01 Jan 2019 06:30:31 +0000
  Release file created at: Fri, 04 Jan 2019 08:05:12 +0000
Get:6 http://ubuntu.vargonen.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [476 kB]
Get:7 http://ubuntu.vargonen.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en [177 kB]
Get:8 http://ubuntu.vargonen.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [245 kB]
Get:9 http://ubuntu.vargonen.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [55,7 kB]
Get:10 http://ubuntu.vargonen.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [105 kB]
Get:11 http://ubuntu.vargonen.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages [6.928 B]
Get:12 http://ubuntu.vargonen.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [6.992 B]
Get:13 http://ubuntu.vargonen.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted Translation-en [3.076 B]
Get:14 http://ubuntu.vargonen.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [706 kB]
Get:15 http://ubuntu.vargonen.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [698 kB]
Fetched 414 kB in 1s (287 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.vargonen.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/93358166c270b6b92fa9b2f22a2b48682eab53091a898321d887541133721297  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:412704 [weak]
    - SHA256:93358166c270b6b92fa9b2f22a2b48682eab53091a898321d887541133721297
    - SHA1:18d14381256ffb6581e1a46b11d911a3cfe6c7ad [weak]
    - MD5Sum:925906a34ad2a7f04f96fa373fb4d672 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:8963f74a7233a0b6d3fef6305755210d987563d34f3d4f9baad34985c3f2f2f8
    - SHA1:4fe0dbdb757e94d9217ae262253ffa29737b92fa [weak]
    - MD5Sum:12d989921f2d8efe120ea70cb64ac867 [weak]
    - Filesize:412704 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Tue, 01 Jan 2019 06:30:31 +0000
   Release file created at: Fri, 04 Jan 2019 08:05:12 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Also when I make `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`, this is the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.6.5-3) but 3.6.5-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried nearly everything in the existing posts but nothing solve the problem.

Edit:
uname -m    :
x86_64

cat /etc/apt/sources.list    :

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe
# deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Comment: "I tried nearly everything", well. Did you tried to switch download mirror with `software-properties-gtk`?

Comment: Thanks but how can I make this?

Comment: As @N0rbert suggested, try to change repository url via `software-properties-gtk` > `Download from` and pick up different host.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/53087/66509 for screenshots.

Comment: That error message stemmed from a package security check related to the repository where you fetched the packages. In any case, try `sudo apt clean` to clean your local cache.

Comment: I did software-propertiens-gtk thing but after updating cache it gives me the same mismatch error. Also sudo apt clean doesn't change anything,

Comment: please check out  outputs of `uname -m` and  `cat  /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: I have added the outputs of that two commands.

Comment: Your sources list mixed. You can recreate new one using following link : https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ but at fist back up existing one with `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list  /etc/apt/sources.list.bak` then create new file with the same name `sources.list` in that directory (/etc/apt/) then paste the list you generated in the link. Only pick up `main`, `restricted`, `universe`, `multiverse`ones.

Comment: Try this at first:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065888/impossible-to-install-with-apt-get-python-missing

Comment: I found another similar issue here https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-core/issues/1780 . According to that report you also need to add `Important Security Updates`, `Recommended Updates`

Comment: thanks. Finally it is normal. I have made both of them but I don't know which one solved the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) and [Trouble downloading packages list due to a “Hash sum mismatch” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)